# OR condition in django templates

Tags: django-templates

Is there a way to implement conditional OR inside templates?
{% if %} would see if true or not...but what i'm looking for is
to implement smthing when {% if %} OR {% if %}..thanks

Answer (score 104, accepted):

in Django 1.2, you can use OR inside an IF tag...see the [built-in template tags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#boolean-operators)

```
{% if var1 == 'val1' or var2 == 'val2' %}
```

Comment: I wanted to do something like this, but I guess I need a custom template tag to do it (as you can in python): {% x or y %}  # I want to output the 1st one that is not null. I know you can do it w/ a more complex if statement.

Comment: @radtek, you can use the [firstof tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#firstof) for that pattern: `{% firstof x y %}`.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the [firstof](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#firstof) template tag. It works similar to an "or":

```
var1 or var2
```

will use var1, if it is True or var2, if it is False. Exacly like this statement in the template:

```
{% firstof var1 var2 %}
```